# unable to use RAID disk during ubuntu 18.04 server installation (curtin installer)

Tags: server, partitioning, 18.04, raid, mdadm

I create a RAID 5 Volume with 5 Hard Disks by Hardware RAID, and intend to install ubuntu-server 18.04 by USB.

First I encounter `MODSIGN: Couldn't get UEFI db list`, `unable to open /dev/sda`
[image]

after few seconds it automatically jumped to ubuntu installation scene.
next error happened at partition. I am going store OS System (`/`, `/boot`) under a non-RAID Hard Disk separated from RAID Volume, and put `/home` under RAID Disk, as long as I selected any RAID Disk, the failed screne will show:

`An error occurred during installation
curtin command install ...`

[image]

more detail log:
`mdadm: (non-fatal) write to /sys/class/block/md127/md/sync_max failed Permission denied`
[image]

I can successfully install ubuntu-server 18.04 on a Non-RAID Disk, but this error happened at any time I choose a RAID Disk to for whatever partition like `/`, `/boot` or `/home`. 
How to solve it ?

Answer (score 3):

I have the same error.

Why?
You use this Ubuntu server version http://releases.ubuntu.com/18.04.1/ubuntu-18.04.1-live-server-amd64.iso named `live-server`.
This version use new [subiquity](https://github.com/CanonicalLtd/subiquity) installation system without RAID support.

Solution: if you want to install Ubuntu with RAID, you need to use Ubuntu with old installation system available here: http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/releases/bionic/release/

Comment: Thank you harobed, alternative is the right way. I figured they got it all worked out since it's an option again in the live-server install. I figured wrong...